# Type "any" has no subscript members in alamofire 4 iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

i Know this Question can be Duplicate. But i was trying to find out this solution in stake overflow. unfortunately i did't figured out The right answer. Here what i have done.

i was trying to Access Youtube data using alamofire. in my viewDidLoad

```
    let API_KEY = "**************"
    let UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID = "PLqQMDoH89jqEoHMTsxxyMz1Hym_pOViq6"
    let CHANNEL_ID = "UCcMUpFCaFhlyjZyy9d9LeRA"
    let parameters = ["part":"snippet","channelId":CHANNEL_ID,"playListId":UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID,"key":API_KEY]

    Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

        if let JSON = response.result.value{

            for video in JSON["item"] as! NSArray {
                print(video)
            }

        }
    }
```

it's give me error Type "any" has no subscript members

Also  i was try another way but This also give me Error

```
  Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists", 
    parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: 
   nil).responseJSON { (response) in



        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let JSON = response.result.value as! [[String : Any]]!{
                for video in JSON["item"] as! NSArray {
                                      print(video)
                 }
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print("There is an error")
            break
        }

    }
```

it's give a errors and tell that can not subscript a value of type '[[string:any]]' with an index of type string

Comment: READ the JSON. It's very very easy. There are only 2 (two !) collection types: array (`[]`) and dictionary (`{}`). This JSON starts clearly with a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Issue it here:
`if let JSON = response.result.value as! [[String : Any]]!`

First: if you're using optional chaining (`if let`) dont use force cast (`as!` and `[[String : Any]]!`).

Secondly, your JSON is not a `Dictionary`, but an `Array` of `Dictionaries`.

Try instead:
`if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String : Any]`

Also, when you try

```
if let JSON = response.result.value{

    for video in JSON["item"] as! NSArray {
    print(video)
    }
}
```

you're not casting `JSON` variable to `Dictionary`, you merely check if `JSON` is not nil.

Comment: Now i am trying this way
Now i am trying this way    
if let JSON = response.result.value  as? [String: Any]{
               
                for video in JSON["item"] as! NSArray {
                    print(video)
                }
              
            }
            
But getting  This  Fatal error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: What should i do now. i am really confused

Comment: Looks like your JSON does not contain "item" element. Edit your question and post your JSON there

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-cast on an ANY variable type, you can cast by using [String:[String:Any]]

Comment: So what should i do now??

Comment: Cast directly as a Type like NSArray or NSDictionnary. And IF you really prefer casting by using the [:] method, just change the any by the type for exemple [String:[String:String]]

Comment: Now i am trying this way Now i am trying this way if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any]{ for video in JSON["item"] as! NSArray { print(video) } } But getting This Fatal error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value